# My chart will not center in the middle of my page

Tags: html, css, structure

My chart on https://gamebreakerfundraising.com/#plans wont center in the middle of the page.  tags didn't seem to help, unless I was just placing them wrong.. Any ideas?

Comment: Please add to code directly and not in external sources. In FF on linux it is centered, what browser are you using?

Comment: Rather than adding a link to your website, you should ideally paste some code from it, using the markup tools provided. Links are dangerous to paste!

Comment: FF34/W7 : centered / no code, no detail, no research effort shown ...

Comment: Centred in Chrome too

Comment: Windows with chrome looks centered.

Comment: what browser, os and screen resolution are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Theme.css, line 915:

```
#home #pricing .charts .chart.first {
    /* float: right; REMOVE */
    /* left: 12px; REMOVE */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

At least that seems to do it, using dev tools. Looks like you copied it from somewhere without reading.

(also, try changing width of your window - the table will get messed up. Not very responsive design!)